# Why does disabling a submit button prevent my on submit event handler from being triggered, and how do I work around this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[event handler gets called](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/xMJeX/)

```
<form>
    <input/>
    <button onclick="this.form.submit();">submit</button>
</form>​
```

[event handler does not get called](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/272tw/)

```
<form>
    <input/>
    <button onclick="var btn=this;btn.disabled=true;setTimeout(function(){btn.disabled=false;},1500);this.form.submit();">submit</button>
</form>​
```

Without modifying the `<button>` HTML, is there some way I can bind an event the to the form submit? It doesn't seem to fire if I disable the button before submitting the form.

---

I think this only happens in **Chrome** (tested on Ubuntu and Win7). Both fiddles work in Win7 Firefox 11.

Comment: If the button is disabled there's not going to be any events activated on it, but I'm not really clear what the point of the button is if you're not using it to submit the form?

Comment: @robertc: I'm not binding any events to the button itself though, I'm binding to the form. And what do you mean? The button *does* submit the form. I just disable it for a second and a half to prevent double clicks. I need to update a hidden input immediately before the form gets submitted so I can pass some extra data along.

Comment: you can submit the form still...just not with the button

Comment: You've not got anything bound to the `form` - your event handler is on the `button`

Comment: @robertc: How so? The JS reads `$('input').closest('form').submit(...)` -- where in there have I referenced `button`?

Comment: If you want to ask a question about some different code, why not put that code in the question instead of what you have there?

Comment: In response to your deleted answer: The thing is that `<input/>` is a complex widget that's built in PHP and JavaScript. I need to populate a hidden input just before the form gets submitted; I don't want to build dependencies into the other form elements. Disabling the button just prevents double-clicks; the form still gets submitted whether or not I disable that button, because I'm calling `this.form.submit()` explicitly. So how does disabling some random button prevent the form submit handlers from being called?

Comment: @robertc: How am I asking about different code? All the code is in those fiddles. In this first scenario my event gets called, in the second it doesn't. Why not, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Put the code that's in your fiddles in the question.

Answer (score 1):

if you move the function out of the button element it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/272tw/8/
or if you need to keep it in the button putting it in an anon function works also http://jsfiddle.net/272tw/9/

Comment: Your 2nd example only seems to work because it causes a syntax error which causes the onclick event to not run. **Edit:** Your first example has a syntax error too: "Uncaught ReferenceError: submitForm is not defined "

Comment: huh odd, it was because the function was in the scope of the onload beacause that it is the default of jsfiddle to wrap the javascript in it, http://jsfiddle.net/272tw/16/ this seems to be what you wanted in terms of disabling the button but the submiting function doesn't fire I'm not too sure why but you could just do any data manipulation in the submitForm function any way then just call btn.form.submit()

Comment: You're still breaking the "Without modifying the <button> HTML" requirement. The code to generate that button is used in many places, I can't modify it without breaking a lot of things. I can create a new button, but then my input becomes dependent on it (i.e., it's not modular/re-usable). Hence why I want to hook into the submit event.

Comment: you can just hijack the button click event using jQuery (can be done in javascript but it you are including jQuery may as well use it) like this http://jsfiddle.net/272tw/17/ you will need to use a more seperfic selector to get only the buttons you want to change but I had assumed this was simplifyed to make the problem easier to see

Comment: if you don't know what the function in the onclick bit is you can do this http://jsfiddle.net/272tw/18/